# Splash icon in android 12 is truncated

Tags: android, android-splashscreen

I am developing a splash screen using the library `androidx.core:core-splashscreen`.

As shown in the official documentation, the icon size of `windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon` is set to `288x192`, but when the app is run on an api level 31 or higher device, the icon appears to be truncated.

Is there any way to solve this?

**[google splash guide]**
[image]

**[My themes.xml]**

```xml
<style name="AppTheme.Splash" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/color_aeaeae</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/splash_icon</item>
    <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar</item>
</style>
```

**[My splash_icon.xml]**

```xml
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:width="288dp"
        android:height="288dp"
        android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <item
        android:width="192dp"
        android:height="192dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_sick"
        android:gravity="center" />
```

**[Screenshot]**
[image]

위의 스크린샷에서 가운데 아이콘은 원래 이런 모양입니다.
[image]

Comment: Try reducing size of icon drawable further < 192dp.